# Changing the category list order in Magento

Tags: magento

I already know that you can drag and drop the categories in the Magento dashboard to change the order of categories in your store but I was wondering, is it possible to make some kind of ranking for each category (this will change) and the order of the categories list would depend on their ranking? If it is, how do I go about doing something like this?

Comment: You could create a new category attribute for rank then run a cron job to update the position attributes.

Comment: Thanks. Can you point me to an article with an example of running a cron job?